# Is there any way to quickly initialize memory to known values after malloc()?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have a program in C for which I need to initialize arrays with initial values.
This program has been done in two versions, one with statically allocated memory and the other with dynamically allocated memory via *malloc()*  (in each case both the size and the initial values are known a priori).

In the first case the arrays are initialized via an header that contain their definition such as.

`float test_data[FEATURES][N][SAMPLES_BATCH]  = {-0.715339, -0.50792, -0.307726, ...,};`

For the second case, on the other hand, I was wondering if there was a way to initialize the memory once allocated quickly otherwise the alternative would be to load them from files.

Comment: you can't mind-meld the data you want to your memory, it has to come from somewhere. If it's completely "random", you need to hardcode it or read it from a file. If there's a pattern to it, setup a loop. If you want to initialize with a single value you can use `calloc` for a one-liner.

Comment: ... with the all-bits-zero single value, that is.  `calloc` doesn't allow you a choice.

Comment: Can you speak a bit to the objective of preparing versions of the program with different memory allocation strategies?  In particular, since you apparently have a static-duration data version already, makes a dynamic-allocation version of any interest whatever?

Comment: Also, are you locked into dynamic allocation via `malloc()`?  Because you might consider instead putting the data in a file and *mapping* that into memory.  Your `malloc()` may use `mmap()` behind the scenes in some cases anyway, and your program loader likely uses memory mapping to get the data into memory in the static-allocation version, so this is not so wildly different as it may sound.

Comment: *"otherwise the alternative would be to load them from files"* You answered your own question. Either the values are in the executable file (statically allocated memory), or they are in a separate file (dynamically allocated memory). Either way, they are in some file.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The code will be executed in an embedded system and the usage of the dynamic allocation could be a way to eventually manage better the memory. Moreover there are lots of piece of code that are repeated in the first version that cannot be put in a function due to the fact that the size of the arrays that should be specified as parameters changes each time. With the second version instead I would pass only the pointers. Coding directly the data in the executable as in the first case would have been a way to gain performance over reading a file.

Comment: @JohnBollinger oh right,, whoops. Thought `calloc` let you supply an initial byte value for some reason .. nope.

Comment: @Dresult, are you saying that the version you already have that uses static allocation does not do everything you want the program to do?  If so, then why did you even bring it up?

Comment: @Dresult, note well that `malloc` is usually considered a big no-no for memory-constrained embedded systems.

Comment: @Dresult "-0.715339, -0.50792, -0.307726" --> narrow range of values hints that data may be stored in code (or file) with a reduced footprint.  Post more info about the data: range count, precision, etc ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a static array that contains the initial values, and `memcpy` it to the allocated memory.

```
static float init_data[] = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
float *test_data = malloc(sizeof init_data);
memcpy(test_data, init_data, sizeof init_data);
```

Comment: Yes, but this means that the memory required is doubled, or not ?

Comment: @Dresult  Yes, but you need to store the initial values *somewhere*.

Comment: This is pretty much _exactly_ how the language initializes your static `array[]` behind the scenes.

Comment: No, @Dúthomhas, not exactly.  The initial values of an array with static storage duration are already in the array at the beginning of its lifetime, which is at the beginning of the execution of the program.  They are not copied in from elsewhere, so as to require double the space, at least not as far as C semantics are concerned. They do take up space in the executable image, of course, but that's a different question.

Comment: But then you do not need that `malloc` at all

Comment: @Dresult Unless there is a pattern to the data that can be easily determined programmatically in a loop (actually, for 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, there is!), this memcpy is an efficient way to  initialize the allocated memory with known values. It is certainly more  efficient than coding individual assignment statements for every element.

Answer (score 0):

> with dynamically allocated memory via malloc() (in each case both the
> size and the initial values are known a priori).

Then you do not need to dynamically allocate memory at all. But you do have a few options:

1. Read the data from a file.
2. Initialize an array with the values and then copy it to the allocated chunk with `memcpy()`, as shown in @dbush's answer.
3. Map the file into memory with `mmap()`.

Answer (score 0):

> (in each case both the size and the initial values are known a priori).

If the size and initial values is known a priori, the most efficient way to initialize it is with global variables in the data segment, initialized in the declaration.  This makes the program to initialize the `.data` segment with the actual values, and as soon as the program is loaded, the variables already have the initial values stored, no need to copy or execute code to initialize them is done.  The same process (the `exec(2)` call) that generates the segments for the program text is used to initalize the global variables.

If you declare a variable in a local context (inside a function as an automatic variable) and you provide an initializer (as you do in the code you post, assuming the variables are automatic)  the initializer requires code to actually initialize the local variables.  This can be reduced to a hidden call to `memcpy()` in the function preamble to initialize the values from a static memory area in the initialized data segment.  This is not as efficient as the last paragraph above.

In the case of dynamically allocated memory, you can use the same approach and initialize the data by copying the initial values from a static series of constant values, stored in static storage.

```
extern struct my_data_structure my_data_initials; /* where the inital values are stores */
struct my_data_structure *my_var = malloc(sizeof *my_var);
*my_var = my_var_initials; /* structure assignment is permitted in C */
```